# New command line feature

Tags: instance, google-compute-engine

I noticed there is a new "Command line" link within the instance form (Compute Engine). While it is being populated when creating a new instance, it is empty on existing ones.
Is it a known bug ?

Answer (score 0):

The command line option for the existing instances in the project has been removed. Now it only shows while you are creating the new instance. However, for the existing ones you can see the REST Equivalent.